# How can I use couch.js in a couch app?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchapp

CouchDB 1.1 comes with a very useful Javascript file called couch.js. I can locate it at http://localhost:5984/_utils/script/couch.js on my Couch instance.

I would like to use this script in a CouchApp. In particular I want to be able to run it from inside Javascript functions for [update handlers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) and [views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API). The file does not look CommonJS compliant, but I tried it anyway. I copied it to the lib directory of my couchapp. I tried to include it using CommonJS' require statement, but that fails to load. I tried the following:

```
var couchdb = require('lib/couch.js');
```

Can anybody help me to load it into a Javascript function? As I search the web I find help for including it in HTML documents, like so:

```
<script src="/_utils/script/couch.js"></script>
```

Obviously that will not work in my Javascript functions.

Also, if there is a way that I can include it from the _utils directory and not have to copy it into my couchapp lib directory, I would prefer to do that. But that is just an extra bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *could* add the exports method to make it CommonJS compliant, you would not want to use couch.js inside your views and update handlers. The couch.js file is designed to run inside a javascript environment that supports ajax. The couchdb javascript environment does not expose any ajax functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For it you will need to change the couch.js's source and add a `exports.CouchDB = CouchDB;` at the end of the file (check the license before doing that. I'm not a lawyer). Than after doing `var couchdb = require('lib/couch.js');` in your code just do `var somevarname = new couchdb.CouchDB(/*parameters*/);`